# Show that the equation has a periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been learning differential equations and need help with this exercise:

$$
x^{\prime \prime}+\left(5 x^{4}-9 x^{2}\right) x^{\prime}+x^{5}=0
$$
I've tried to write it as a system:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x^{\prime}=y \\
y^{\prime}=\left(9 x^{2}-5x^4 \right) y-x^{5}
\end{array}
$$
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that, when you consider a small neighborhood of zero, $x^2$ is the most powerful and $y’$ has the same sign as $y$. So the zero point is unstable. But when $x$ is big enough, higher powers dominate, so trajectories become attracted to zero. The only consensus between those two phenomena is a cycle somewhere in the middle.

Try to find an appropriate Lyapunov function to make it formal. Also, I’m not sure, but such problem should have a known general solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is often helpful to combine the first two terms in
$$
x''+c(x)x'+g(x)=0
$$
to form the second variable $y=x'+C(x)$, $C'(x)=c(x)$, in the first order system, which now is
\begin{align}
x'&=y-C(x)\\
y'&=-g(x)
\end{align}
Then you get a phase portrait like

[image]

where the blue line is the null-cline $y=C(x)=x^5-3x^3$. This has the typical almost rectangular or trapezoidal structure of a fast-slow system, a Lienard dynamic, ... which is commonly demonstrated on the van der Pol oscillator $\ddot x+\mu(x^2-1)\dot x+x=0$. It is clearly visible that a limit cycle has to exist, however to find a Lyapunov function or to demonstrate that in other ways seems not so easy.

See [Trajectory in the Lienard system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408772/trajectory-in-the-lienard-system) on how  one can start to show that solutions starting "outwards" have to spiral inwards. Such a spiral then also provides a trapping region.